# Can a Pakistani citizen transit through Netherlands or Switzerland if traveling with an official passport?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, pakistani-citizens

I am going to UK to attend an official meeting and have UK visit visa. Can I go to UK through Switzerland or Amsterdam. I have an official passport of Pakistan but I do not have a Schengen visa.

Comment: Rules for entry with official and diplomatic passports are set by the individual Schengen member states, add are rules for airport transit.  Answering this question therefore requires checking the rules for both Switzerland and the Netherlands, I believe.  I don't have time at the moment but will do it later if nobody else has done so by then.

Comment: Official, diplomatic and special are all different things.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=PK&PASSTYPES=TYPE&selDest=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20destination%28s%29%20above&TR=NL&TR=CH&selTrans=Netherlands%0D%0ASwitzerland&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by Airlines:

**For the Netherlands**:

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of Pakistan, holding
>   onward tickets transiting by the same or first
>   connecting aircraft **AND** meeting one of the following
>   conditions:
>
> [...]
>
> - holding a visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus,
>     Ireland (Rep.), Japan, Romania, USA or **United Kingdom**,
>     traveling to any non-Schengen Member State;
> - returning from Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland
>     (Rep.), Japan, Romania, USA or **United Kingdom** after having
>     used the visa;

**For Switzerland**

> Visa required, **except** for Holders of confirmed onward tickets in transit only through Geneva (GVA) or Zurich (ZRH)

So **yes**, you can transit in the Netherlands or Switzerland if the trip is in a single booking.

Comment: There is a difference between a Pakistani official and diplomatic passport.

Comment: @greatone Edited. Timatic has a "Normal", "Seaman" and "Government duty" Option. This is for "government duty" which applies to both official **and** diplomatic passports

Answer (score 3):

*The other answer references Timatic, I will, however, try to answer your question with direct references to official governmental sites.*

---

**Question 1:**

> *Can I transit through **Netherlands** without airport transit visa?*

**Answer**:

> You only need an airport transit visa if your nationality appears on
> [the list of countries whose nationals require a visa](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/binaries/netherlandsandyou/documents/publications/2017/01/01/list-of-countries-whose-nationals-need-an-airport-transit-visa-in-the-netherlands-en/List_of_countries_whose_nationals_need_an_airport_transit_visa_in_the%20Netherlands%20(EN).pdf) (*Pakistan is in this list*). However, an
> airport transit visa is not required if you:
>
> - have a visa or residence permit for a country in the Schengen Area, the EU *(UK is here)* or the EEA.

So **yes, you can transit through Netherlands without airport transit visa.** [(Source)](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/travel-and-residence/visas-for-the-netherlands/airport-transit-visa).

---

**Question 2:**

> *Can I transit through **Switzerland** without airport transit visa?*

**Answer**:

> Citizens of the following states are required to hold an airport visa:
>
> - ...
> - Pakistan
>
> However, holders of a valid visa issued by one of the following states are exempted from the requirement to hold an airport transit visa:
>
> - ...
> - Great Britain (*They mean UK*)

So **yes, you can transit through Switzerland without airport transit visa.** [(Source)](https://www.sem.admin.ch/content/dam/data/sem/rechtsgrundlagen/weisungen/visa/bfm/bfm-anh01-liste2-e.pdf).